# Google Maps API Event Listener For Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created three markers using Google Maps API. Is there a way that I can add an event listener to each marker so that they will work independently when the corresponding marker is active? I would like to display a message if the user is getting closer to a marker, specifically with bounds_changed. I want to continue giving the user a message until they get to a zoom level of say 5.

```
    <script>
      var map;
      var score;
      score = 0;
      function initMap() {
        var chicago = {lat: 41.8781, lng: -87.6298};
        var indianapolis = {lat: 39.7684, lng: -86.1581};
        var oklahomaCity = {lat: 35.4819, lng: -97.5084};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0},
          zoom: 1
});
        var chicagoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: chicago,      

});

        var oklahomaCityMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: oklahomaCity,
});

        var indianapolisMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: indianapolis,

});

if (score==0) {
    chicagoMarker.setMap(map)
}

if (score==1) {
    oklahomaCityMarker.setMap(map)
}

if (score==2) {
    indianapolisMarker.setMap(map)
}


chicagoMarker.setVisible(false);
indianapolisMarker.setVisible(false);
oklahomaCityMarker.setVisible(false);
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCuvsCAF0gVmwv6AF0SoA3xBjV66RG4r7o&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(chicagoMarker, 'click', function(){

//do something
})
```

Comment: Now my problem is that my map disappears completely when I activate the event listener

Comment: No, my browser is loading a blank page when I activate the event listener. I tried to implement it under both the if state and under the declaration of my marker variable.

Comment: it may be because you were getting error 'marker is not defined' try edited code

Comment: I am trying this, but still nothing

Comment: if (score==0) {
 chicagoMarker.setMap(map)
 google.maps.event.addListener(chicagoMarker,'click',function(){
  if (map.getBounds.contains(chicagoMarker)){
   window.alert("Good Job!");
   }
  }
 
}

Comment: open developer tools of browser and look for errors?

Comment: Okay I figured out why the map wouldn't show up, but I am not receiving my alert box as i zoom in on my location.

Comment: i did not understand your comment